# Angular auto table of contents

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

I am trying to make an automatic table of contents in angular. For this I need to get the elements (h1, h2..etc) by tag. Does anyone know the equivalent function of jquery `document.getelementbytagname ('h1, h2, h3')` in angular? ViewChildren doesn't work as it can't find items by tag. ViewChildren works with #id and with components. I need help! My thanks in advance for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then this will solve your problem

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1><h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1><h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLElement){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.document.getElementsByTagName('h1'));
  }
}
```

Comment: By doing that would you be using jquery?

Comment: No, only angular. You can see an example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-getelementbytag